# Sinatra::Reloader not reloading files in Docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra

I'm trying to setup a simple sinatra app in a Docker container. I've setup modular Sinatra app on rack with `config.ru`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/reloader"

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/controllers/*.rb'].each {|file| require file}

#map controllers
map('/') {run WebController}
```

Single controller `/controllers/hello.rb`:

```
class WebController < Sinatra::Base

  register Sinatra::Reloader

  get '/' do
    "Hello World"
  end

  get '/test' do
    "Hello World I'm a docker app"
  end
end
```

And here's the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0
MAINTAINER Bugs Bunny <bbunny@rubyplus.com>

RUN apt-get update && \ apt-get install -y net-tools

# Install gems
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV HOME /root
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install

# Upload source
COPY . $APP_HOME

# Start server
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup", "-o", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]
```

The `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rack'
gem 'rack-test'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib'
```

When runing `docker run -p 3000:3000 sinatra` the WEBrick output:

```
[2019-02-24 20:43:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2019-02-24 20:43:08] INFO  ruby 2.4.0 (2016-12-24) [x86_64-linux]
[2019-02-24 20:43:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3000
```

The problem is, when run in docker container `Sinatra::Reloader` doesn't refresh modified controller file anymore.

I've tried running the same command `bundle exec rackup -o 0.0.0.0 -p 3000` on the host machine and reloading happens as expected. If I edit the `/controllers/hello.rb` after refreshing the page on `localhost:3000` changes are shown immediately.

When I run the same app in Docker the reloading stops working.

Any help appreciated, tnx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with Docker: once an image is built, you can not (easily) alter its contents anymore except by rebuilding it. So, when you change the contents of `controller/hello.rb` on your host system, the change does not propagate inside of the image. You can [use Docker volumes to mount your host directory inside of the container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), so that any changes you make in the host system will propagate inside of the container (just don't forget to rebuild it before deploying!). You could [also declare that in a docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) file for easier maintenance!

Comment: Yep, in first attempt i didn't use docker-compose, once I set it up, and synced the volumes, everything works. tnx ;)